# Rails dataTables jquery-datatables-column-filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I'm using a Railscast way to remotely access Rails data using Ajax.  It works fine.

[Railscast 340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast)

Now, I'm trying to add the jquery-datatables-column-filter plug-in.

Here is my coffeescript:

```
$("#workorders").dataTable(
  sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
  bProcessing: true
  bServerSide: true
  bFilter: false
  sAjaxSource: $('#workorders').data('source')
  sDom: "T<\"clear\">lfrtip"
 ).columnFilter()
```

But, when I even click on NEXT (to get the 2nd page of workorders), I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sServerMethod' of undefined  jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:8754
DataTable.defaults.fnServerData jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:8754
oTable.fnSettings.fnServerData jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js?body=1:330
_fnAjaxUpdate jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:1898
_fnDraw jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:1431
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:2876
fnClickHandler jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:11665
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:4800
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:3075
elemData.handle
```

And searching a column doesn't work either.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

UPDATE1

I tried to even simplify with another index listing (without ajax).

This is the coffeescript:

```
  $("#dataTable1").dataTable().columnFilter()
```

And when I try to search on a column, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of null   jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:5586
fnFilter jquery.dataTables.js?body=1:5586
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js?body=1:65
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:3075
elemData.handle
```

Comment: Maybe it's too late but were you able to implement filtering?

Comment: I ended up changing it to use Ransack.  Basically searching instead of filtering.  It works great!

Answer (score 0):

Did you drop the Column Filter plugin js into your /vender/assets/javascripts dir?  And, then reference in your application.js:

```
//= require jquery.dataTables.columnFilter
```

Comment: #steakchaser Yes.  Currently, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sServerMethod' of undefined` in the browser console.

Comment: I tried adding `sServerMethod: "GET"`. But, that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change line 316 in jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js from this:

> oTable.fnSettings().fnServerData = function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

to this:

> oTable.fnServerData = function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {